# About the file upload

Tags: file, cordova, upload

In this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007239/12122173. Does the form append comes after the file assignment? And which one should I append, imgblob or file?

Comment: Maybe try to ask in the comment section of link you post so the author can reply to you.

Comment: Yeah tnx, I'm kinda new to this.